# Discrepancy in WordPress Website Content and Dashboard after Migration to Hostinger

Tags: wordpress

The problem is that there is a noticeable discrepancy between the website content and the dashboard in my Hostinger account. The content on my live website, as seen by visitors, does not match what I had on my old hosting provider. Moreover, when I access the dashboard to make updates or modifications, the content displayed there is also different from what should be reflected on the live site. see screenshot

[websites dashbord screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI9Sy.png)

how to fix this issue?